Regressing on Residuals
I have a time series dataset (Local Gov. bond yields and probable determinants). Due to structural breaks in different exogenous variables in different time points, I have an idea of regressing a set of parameters with similar structural break times first (dividing dataset and estimating models, merging residuals), and then regressing other part of variables on residuals of the first estimation. Is it a correct way to do? Do I break any assumptions if residuals of the first model are not normally distributed?

Could you be more explicit? E.g. dividing dataset and estimating models, merging residuals is very brief. Also, what do you mean by regressing <...> parameters? Typically, you regress a dependent variable on one or more regressors (explanatory variables). Consider editing your post to address these questions.

@RichardHardy Probably I was too specific about dividing the dataset. The idea I have is to regress yields on monetary policy indicators first, then take residuals of this model and use them as endogenous variable for another set of exogenous variables (like Debt/GDP and others). There is a reason why I can't estimate the model with all variables together at one take, but let's omit it for now.
The question I have is if it is a correct way to do? And do I break any assumptions if residuals of the first model are not normally distributed?

What is the reason actually?

@RichardHardy The reason is that exogenous variables have many structural breaks that appear at different times. If i had one or two breaks in time series I would just split the dataset by these breaks and perform local regressions. But my dataset is not such big to split original dataframe every time any exogenous variable experiences a structural break. So I though I could split the original dataset only at places of struct.breaks in one variable, estimate models, take residuals from them, merge and use as an endog. var against another variable, which i could split in other time periods.

OK, now that information could be edited into your post, making it more detailed and easier to follow.
